# Jquery plugin behave different on different instances

Tags: jquery, plugins, instance

Im trying to write a simple autocomplete plugin for jquery (for learning purpose").
If u look at the DOM after the JS has run, there is to div after the input fields, but only the 2nd has the ul inside it. Why? it should be work identically on both input, shouldnt it?

http://jsbin.com/avomez/1/edit and Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
 <input class="city" type="text" />
 <input class="city" type="text" />
```

**JS**

```
$.fn.autocomplete = function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var drpd = $('<div class="dropdown" />');
    var ul = $('<ul class="city" />');

    self.after(drpd);
    drpd.append(ul);



};

$("input.city").autocomplete();
```

Comment: Try using a `change` for the correct input. `$("input.city").change(function(){$(this).autocomplete();});`

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do? I initially thought you wanted a div to show up when you type in the text field. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You going to need to iterate and also return back the `this` (jQuery object) to make a plugin. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/avomez/3/

**Reason:**

1. The `$('input.city')` return an array of elements, you should iterate on single elements to make sure you are not messing it up. Your original problem was a good example here.
2. Returning jQuery object allows you to chain like `$('input.city').autocomplete().addClass('someclass');`

**Code:**

```
$.fn.autocomplete = function(){
  return this.each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var drpd = $('<div class="dropdown" />');
    var ul = $('<ul class="city" />');

    self.after(drpd);
    drpd.append(ul);
  });    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

add this lines

```
$.fn.autocomplete = function(){
    return this.each(function(){  //ADD
    var self = $(this);
    var drpd = $('<div class="dropdown" />');
    var ul = $('<ul class="city" />');
    self.after(drpd);
    drpd.append(ul);
    });                          //ADD
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `change` event for finding the correct input:

```
$("input.city").change(function(){
     $(this).autocomplete();
});
```

Comment: i have tried it but it didnt work: http://jsbin.com/avomez/2/edit Why should this fix my problem?